# Is there a mysqli driver for Kohana 3.x

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, kohana

Aside from the more advanced options such as accessing stored procs and handling multiple result sets, I'd love to start using mysqli in my Kohana project so I can set the MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE option.

I'm trying to stay on topic, but just so you know the exact context in which I'm trying to use this option - I'd like to have the SQL results to automatically tell PHP which columns were INTs so my JSON object properties don't have quotes around them if they're not strings.

thanks in advance - first post!

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. It should be very easy to make one based off of the mysql driver though.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no official Kohana database driver for use with mysqli, there are a few you'll find on GitHub. One of which is: https://github.com/cdomigan/kohana-database-mysqli. It shouldn't be too difficult to fork the repository and add any needed options that you require for your application.